# PostgresConnector: No topics discovered on this connector

Tags: postgresql, docker, apache-kafka, debezium

I'm running ladoop/fast-data-dev and using the PostgresConnector from Debezium. I've configured the connector, but no topics are created.

No topics discovered on this connector is the error.

Docker-compose cluster:

```
  kafka-cluster:
    image: landoop/fast-data-dev:latest
    environment:
      ADV_HOST: 127.0.0.1         # Change to 192.168.99.100 if using Docker Toolbox
      RUNTESTS: 0                 # Disable Running tests so the cluster starts faster
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    ports:
      - 2181:2181                 # Zookeeper
      - 3030:3030                 # Landoop UI
      - 8081-8083:8081-8083       # REST Proxy, Schema Registry, Kafka Connect ports
      - 9581-9585:9581-9585       # JMX Ports
      - 9092:9092                 # Kafka Broker
```

The connector is up and running;

```
{
    "name": "PostgresConnector",
    "connector": {
        "state": "RUNNING",
        "worker_id": "127.0.0.1:8083"
    },
    "tasks": [
        {
            "state": "RUNNING",
            "id": 0,
            "worker_id": "127.0.0.1:8083"
        }
    ],
    "type": "source"
}
```

Here's the config I'm using for the connector:

```
name=PostgresConnector
connector.class=io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector
database.dbname=mydb
database.user=mydb
tasks.max=1
database.server.name=postgres_server
database.port=5432
table.whitelist=public.mytable
value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
database.hostname=master
database.password=
value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
key.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
```

Expected a topic to be created.

Answer (score 2):

So, the error was in the sink. The topic needed to be named `postgres_server.public.mytable`